# Column not Exist error although column is in db django

Tags: python, django

The
I m running into an error that column exists. I checked the DB and found that column is present in the database

```
Django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "topic" of relation "post_post" does not exist LINE 1: ... "id", "topic...
```

I have tried the following :
`Post._meta.get_field('topic')` got `django.db.models.fields.CharField: topic`

So the field exists too.